# How to disable metadata tracking in MIKROS Analytics?

Tags: mikros, mikros-analytics, mikros-game-analytics

How can I disable data tracking for specific analytics without removing Mikros package?  Currently, I have Mikros sdk 1.1.0 integrated with my Android game with Unity 2021.3.6f1.  In my Mikros settings I have Auto Initialize Mikros checked.

Answer (score 2):

The scope of the PRIVACY_LEVEL is as follows:

```
1. PRIVACY_LEVEL.DEFAULT
   a) Track Session : TRUE
   b) Track Metadata : TRUE
   c) Track Events : TRUE
   d) Track Memory : TRUE
   e) Track Crash : TRUE
2. PRIVACY_LEVEL.HIGH
   a) Track Session : TRUE
   b) Track Metadata : FALSE
   c) Track Events : TRUE
   d) Track Memory : TRUE
   e) Track Crash : TRUE
3. PRIVACY_LEVEL.EXTREME
   a) Track Session : FALSE
   b) Track Metadata : FALSE
   c) Track Events : FALSE
   d) Track Memory : FALSE
   e) Track Crash : FALSE
```

You can also individually toggle each of the tracking (Session, Metadata, Events, Memory, Crash) by the following way:

```
// to change only session tracking settings (Optional)
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackUserSession(true);

// to change only metadata tracking settings (Optional).
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackUserMetadata(true);

// to change only event logging settings (Optional).
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetEventLogging(true);

// to change only device memory tracking settings (Optional).
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackDeviceMemory(true);

// to change only crash reporting settings (Optional).
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoCrashReporting(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the analytics from Mikros for metadata by adding this to your script:

```
MikrosManager.Instance.ClientConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackUserMetadata(false);
```

Make sure if you do add this to your script that you have this added to the top:

```
import MikrosClient;
import MikrosClient.Analytics;
```

I found this information in the documentation:

ref- https://developer.tatumgames.com/documentation/disable-mikros-analytics

You can also always join the Mikros Slack to communicate with the community and developers here:

ref- https://join.slack.com/t/mikros-community/shared_invite/zt-owl845v6-UMLsx9m8W_8VwSrfvciX8Q

Answer (score 0):

You can disable auto tracking of user metadata, as well as auto tracking of sessions, crash reporting or even disable logging of events completely. This can be done a couple ways. You can do so explicitly,

```
// MIKROS won't track user session information
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackUserSession(false);

// MIKROS won't track user metadata information e.g. device info, network info, ect
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoTrackUserMetadata(false);

// MIKROS won't record app crashes
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAutoCrashReporting(false);

// Even if you logEvents() MIKROS will ignore it. 
// This is a shutoff valve for all logged events.
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetEventLogging(false);

// To have MIKROS not track anything you can use
MikrosManager.Instance.ConfigurationController.SetAllTrackingEnabled(false);
```

Alternatively, you can update the `Configuration` privacy settings.

```
Configuration configuration = Configuration.Builder().SetPrivacyLevel(privacyLevel).Create();
MikrosManager.Instance.InitializeMikrosSDK(configuration);
```

> PRIVACY_LEVEL.DEFAULT (Recommended) MIKROS tracks user metadata and session in the background.
>
> PRIVACY_LEVEL.HIGH MIKROS no longer tracks any metadata information in the background; only session info is tracked.
>
> PRIVACY_LEVEL.EXTREME MIKROS no longer tracks any metadata or session info in the background. Integrators will have to track this manually.

Comment: I have to find the link for this information. I will edit update my answer when I do.